# How to show local variables in Powershell console in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, powershell

How can I during debugging process (.NET application) in Visual Studio 2013 show out local variables of my debugged .NET application in Powershell console?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS 2013 and not Powershell ISE, an alternative is [PowerShell Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f65f845b-9430-4f72-a182-ae2a7b8999d7), which integrates PS commands, console and unit tests in Visual Studio.

Comment: How can I have access to local variables of debugged .NET process from "PowerShell Interactive Window"? For example, to VS I have access via variable $dte

Comment: I apologize but I did not understand what you are trying to achieve. You have a .NET process that you want to access using Powershell ? You can refer     Add-Type -Path "E:\myLibrary.dll" and then create objects like $myObject = New-Object "myLibraryObject" and access those in Powershell console.

Comment: I want to print _existing_ .NET object during debugging in VS via VS Powershell tab. For example, it will allow to print list with filter or other advanced things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging in powershell command prompt use like below:

Console:

```
PS C:\Users\******\Desktop> Set-PSBreakpoint -script ".\1.ps1" -line 4 #setting breakpoint

  ID Script            Line Command           Variable         Action
  -- ------            ---- -------           --------         ------
   0 1.ps1                4


PS C:\Users\******\Desktop> .\1.ps1
Step 1 done
Entering debug mode. Use h or ? for help.

Hit Line breakpoint on 'C:\Users\******\Desktop\1.ps1:4'

At C:\Users\******\Desktop\1.ps1:4 char:1
+ $c = "3"
+ ~~~~~~~~
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\******\Desktop>> $a #printing local variable value
2
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\******\Desktop>>
```

File "1.ps1" is as below:

```
$a = "2"
$b = "3"
Write-Host "Step 1 done"
$c = "3" #putting breakpoint here
$d = "4"
Write-Host "Step 2 done"
$e = "5"
$f = "6"
Write-Host "Step 3 done"
```

If you are using powershell ise you just need to write variable name($a) in console and it will print the value.

Comment: I mean when I debug c# program

Answer (score 0):

In "Package Manager Console" execute command:

```
$dte.Debugger.CurrentStackFrame.Locals
```

The command shows list of local variables (including name):

```
Name         : this
Type         : csharp_tips.PowerShellInDebuggerSamples
DataMembers  : System.__ComObject
Value        : {csharp_tips.PowerShellInDebuggerSamples}
IsValidValue : True
DTE          : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Collection   : System.__ComObject

Name         : doubleArray
Type         : double[]
DataMembers  : System.__ComObject
Value        : {double[3]}
IsValidValue : True
DTE          : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Collection   : System.__ComObject
```

Next step, to get value of the local variables